# React Grid, close the gap between 2 rows

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm, trying to create a 2-D grid of 1000 nodes divided into 20 rows and each row has 50 cols.

[see the grid here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPRfk.png)
I'm trying to close the small gap between the 2 rows but can't. Can anyone help?

grid.jsx

```
const Grid = ({ grid }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      {grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
        return (
          <div key={rowIdx}>
            {row.map((node) => (
              <Node node={node} />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Node

```
const Node = ({ node }) => {
  return <div onClick={() => getNode(node)} className="node"></div>;
};

function getNode(node) {
  console.log("row=", node.row, "col=", node.col);
}
```

the css file

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.node {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(175, 216, 248);
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  /* display: grid; */
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: What if you changed the `.row { margin-top: 100px; }` to `margin-top: 0`?

Comment: it's going to put the grid at mid-top

Comment: vertical-align:top to your inline-block elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've placed the `row` class on the entire grid instead of the rows you are mapping. You can also set the row height to match the height of your nodes + their border (20px + 1px top + 1px bottom).

```
const Grid = ({ grid }) => {
  return (
    <div className="grid"> // <-- set grid classname
      {grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
        return (
          <div key={rowIdx} className="row"> // <-- row class here
            {row.map((node) => (
              <Node node={node} />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  /* display: grid; */
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.node {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(175, 216, 248);
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  height: 22px;
}
```

[image]